# Copy/paste graph to a new sheet and resize

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy a graph and paste it to a new sheet at a specific location and then resize it.

This code just resizes the original graph:

```
Dim ws as worksheet

set ws = worksheets("Sheet2")
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
ws.Paste Destination:=ws.Range("B17")

With ActiveChart.Parent
    .Height = 100 ' resize
    .Width = 250  ' resize
End With
```

I tried to record a macro. It would activate the destination chart with a assigned chart name first (such as "Chart 6" in the below codes) and then do the resize. In my case, the chart name changes all the time so I cannot code it in the macro.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("C3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
With ActiveChart
    .Height = 100 ' resize
    .Width = 250  ' resize
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Chrt1 As ChartObject
    Dim chrt2 As ChartObject


    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set Chrt1 = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1)
    Chrt1.Copy
    ws.Paste Destination:=ws.Range("B17")
    Set chrt2 = ws.ChartObjects(1)
    With chrt2.Chart.Parent
         .Height = 100 ' resize
         .Width = 250  ' resize
     End With
End Sub
```